# Filewatcher for Sharepoint

Tags: vb.net

Am new to stack overflow and new to .net as well.

Here i need your help with File Watcher in vb.net, let me summarize the issue.

as part of my one of the projects i had to create a windows service which will monitor the multiple folders of the server and trigger some .bat file  and i was successful.but the latest request is to monitor the share point as well, but i am unsure how to do that, i tried with UNC and its not working and Service is running on my credentials and i have access to share point

am stuck here, any help is much appreciated.

Venkat